# Some users get the error "Unable to set property" when clicking a custom Javascript button

Tags: javascript, custom-button, pdf

Since a couple of weeks, some of my users have a problem with a custom Javascript button in Classic. They get the error message "Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference". No line number is reported.

The error does not always occur, and after trying two or three times the button does what it is supposed to do, no error message. The used browser is Chrome. I cannot reproduce this message, I clicked dozens of times and for me, the button always works.

This is the code:

```
{
    !REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")
}
{
    !REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/apex.js")
}
var pdfOverlay = QuotePDFPreview.quotePDFObjs['quotePDFOverlay'];
try {
    var verkoopGroep = "{!Quote.Account_verkoopgroep__c}";
    if (verkoopGroep.indexOf("F0") == 0) {
        pdfOverlay.summlid = '0EH580000003OAC';
    } else {
        var taal = "{!Quote.Account_taal__c}";
        switch (taal) {
            case 'Nederlands':
                pdfOverlay.summlid = '0EH58000000GcPS';
                break;
            case 'Engels':
                pdfOverlay.summlid = '0EH58000000GjHG';
                break;
            case 'Duits':
                pdfOverlay.summlid = '0EH58000000Gg9F';
                break;
            case 'Spaans':
                pdfOverlay.summlid = '0EH5800000085ZN';
                break;
            case 'Roemeens':
                pdfOverlay.summlid = '0EH5800000085ZS';
                break;
            case 'Frans':
                pdfOverlay.summlid = '0EH5800000085ZX';
                break;
            case 'Pools':
                pdfOverlay.summlid = '0EH5800000085Zh';
                break;
            case 'Italiaans':
                pdfOverlay.summlid = '0EH5800000085Zc';
                break;
            default:
                pdfOverlay.summlid = '0EH58000000GjHG';
                break;
        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    alert('Er is een fout opgetreden: ' + e);
    pdfOverlay.summlid = '0EH58000000GcPS';
}
;
pdfOverlay.dialog.buttonContents = '<input value=\"{!$Label.Opslaan_naar_offerte}\" class=\"btn\" name=\"save\" onclick=\"QuotePDFPreview.getQuotePDFObject(\'quotePDFOverlay\').savePDF(\'0\',\'0\');\" title=\"Opslaan naar offerte\" type=\"button\" /><input value=\"{!$Label.Offerte_opslaan_en_per_e_mail_verzenden}\" class=\"btn\" name=\"saveAndEmail\" onclick=\"QuotePDFPreview.getQuotePDFObject(\'quotePDFOverlay\').savePDF(\'1\');\" title=\"Offerte opslaan en per e-mail verzenden\" type=\"button\" /><input value=\"{!$Label.Annuleren}\" class=\"btn\" name=\"cancel\" onclick=\"QuotePDFPreview.getQuotePDFObject(\'quotePDFOverlay\').close();\" title=\"Annuleren\" type=\"button\" />';
pdfOverlay.setSavable(true);
pdfOverlay.setContents('/quote/quoteTemplateDataViewer.apexp?id={!Quote.Id}', '/quote/quoteTemplateHeaderData.apexp?id={!Quote.Id}');
pdfOverlay.display();
```

It creates a PDF for a quote and displays it. This code has worked properly for the past 3 years, but all of a sudden some of my users have problems with it.

Note that 'innerHTML' does not occur in the Javascript, so the problem occurs in the QuotePDFPreview library? As I use a fixed version of this library, that should rule out any changes on that part. Could some change in Chrome cause this behavior?

Comment: did you try to have an idea about installed extensions those users have? it could be an extension trying to do something weird.

Comment: That is an idea. The three users are using Chrome within Citrix, which limits what they can do with it. But I could check to see if it is possible to install extensions.

Comment: I checked the extensions section in the Chrome browser within Citrix and it says something like "Your browser is being managed by your organization". That still doesn't tell me whether users have been able to install extensions or not, though...

Comment: do you get the same error when Chrome is in Incognito mode too?(Incognito will disable most of the extensions)

Comment: The problem is the unpredictability of the error. You can click this button 10 times and 10 times there is no problem whatsoever. And then suddenly... boom.

Comment: It sounds like it's a race condition, then.  Usually something is loading fast enough for the next line of JS in the QuotePDFPreview module to execute properly, but other times it isn't.  I assume it's that `setContents` method that's failing, since that likely uses innerHTML.

Comment: By the way, you should consider using a map instead of your switch statement.  Something like `var TAAL_TO_SUMMLID = {Nederlands: '0EH58000000GcPS', ...}; pdfOverlay.summlid = TAAL_TO_SUMMLID[taal];` (forgive my lack of Dutch)

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Charles. Whilst it might not be a good fix, using `setTimeout()` to delay whatever the library is doing might be useful for testing whether introducing an artificial delay gives the page enough time to render before the library starts 'searching' for whatever it's trying to update the innerHtml of.

Comment: I updated the versions of the included Javascript libraries to 47. I checked the difference between versions 37 and 47. There are not many and they seem not to be related to my issue, but I guess it can't hurt.

Comment: As I cannot reproduce the issue that some of my users have some of the time, I am reluctant to do something with timeouts. I fear that it may have more consequences than I intend. The cure might be worse than the disease, so to say.

Comment: Updating the Javascript library versions did not help. Another user reported the problem.

Comment: I have added a delay using setTimeout. I will ask my users to see if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a timing problem. I changed

```
pdfOverlay.display();
```

into

```
setTimeout(function(){pdfOverlay.display();}, 200);
```

and now my users do not have this problem anymore.